# How can I send private message to a new user who joined my server?

Tags: discord.js

I want the person who enters the server will receive from the message. I tried to do something like that, but it did not work:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var joiner = member.user.username;
    const embeddd = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .setTitle(`Hi, ${joiner}.`)
    message.author.send(embeddd); 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```js
> message.author.send(embeddd);
> ```

There is no message parameter in a client's [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event. If you want to send your embed to the member that joined, use the `member` parameter you already have.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#ffffff')
    .setTitle('**Hello!**')
    .setDescription(`Welcome to ${member.guild}.`)
    .setFooter(member.guild.name, member.guild.iconURL);

  member.send(embed)
    .catch(console.error); 
});
```

<sub>See [`GuildMember.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send).</sub>